# ✖ Installing Bundler error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set

Tags: javascript, react-native, macos

✖ Installing Bundler
error Your Ruby version is 2.6.8, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.4

✖ Installing Bundler
error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.

But my Ruby version is 2.7.5

I tried run below commands:

```
yarn global remove react-native-cli "after install again"
rvm install ruby/latest
npm install -g @react-native/cli
```

But nothing works :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I used RVM to install ruby and restarted the terminal. It worked.

Use this to install RVM:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

[Install](https://rvm.io/rvm/basics#installing-rubies) the ruby version you would like (2.7.5 in this case):

```
rvm install 2.7.5
```

This is an open issue in the RN repo. Looks like react-native-cli just cannot figure out that the Ruby version is indeed correct. You can avoid the CLI command by going to the project directory and running:

```
bundle install
cd ios && bundle exec pod install
```

[Link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35053#issuecomment-1294196139)

Comment: if using Macbook M1 then bundle always failing,
I used cd <APP_NAME>
arch -arm64 bundle install
and ffi installation succeeded

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

Then:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score -1):

#### FIXED

From React Native documentation:

> React Native uses this **[version](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/template/_ruby-version)** of Ruby.

To check what is your current version of Ruby

```bash
ruby --version
```

##### 1. Install rbenv

To download the rbenv package with Homebrew, run the following command:

```bash
brew install rbenv
```

Add to `~/.zshrc` or to `~/.bash_profile`:

```bash
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

##### 2. Install Ruby

Install Ruby 2.7.6, please check the latest [version](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/template/_ruby-version):

```bash
rbenv install 2.7.6
```

Switch to use Ruby 2.7.6:

```bash
rbenv global 2.7.6
```

To see the installed versions:

```bash
rbenv versions
```

##### 3. Check it

Create a new React Native project:

```bash
npx react-native@latest init TestApp
```